# What Visual C++ references are worth a look for a Java programmer looking to get up to speed?

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a lot of experience with Java/OO.  There are tons of C++ tutorials/references out there, but I was wondering if there are a few key ones that a Java programmer might find useful when making the transition.

I will be moving from server-side J2EE to Windows Visual C++ desktop programming.

I have googled and found tons of resources, but am overwhelmed and don't know where to best spend my time.  I have only a few days to get a good start.

Is Visual Studio Express / Microsoft Visual C++ the best IDE for me to start with?

Also, any words of wisdom from others who know and work with both languages?

Comment: The express editions don't come with MFC, also I don't think a few days is going to get you very far if you're working with lower level Win32. You may want to look into Qt for rapid development using C++.

Comment: You're moving from server side J2EE to Windows Visual C++ desktop programming? What's next after that? COBOL?

Comment: Slowly working my way backwards from perl

Comment: @Steven: Don't know about Qt for beginner - it tends to replace standard library in SDK and I think in tutorial too, and that can lead to bad habits. Beside that, I like Qt and Qt Creator IDE

Answer (score 2):

The widely recommended books here are Scott Meyers Effective series. "Effective C++", "More Effective C++" and "Effective STL".

I would also recommend the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) and [The C++ Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201700735).

Answer (score 2):

I have been in these shoes before and I constantly find myself referring to two sources:

The first is [C plus plus reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/)

Here you will find the basic standard C and C++ libraries that you will always need.  They are the bread and butter.

The second is [Microsoft's Visual Studio Development Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/visualc/default.aspx).

Here you'll find the linker error support for Visual Studio and their built in libraries.

Don't forget to give [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) a try!  Quite often intellisense breaks in VS2005 if your doing some serious business, though I can't speak for newer versions.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ is a good way to go, you can get the express version for free from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP)

As far as books It really depends what you want to do. I like the Horton book as far as learning Visual C++, GUI, CLR and Database programming. The Lippman book is a very good tutorial on C++, but it only covers the basic language, which is large.

- [This will get you going with basic 
  constructs.(Lippman)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201721481)
- [This will get you going with Visual
  C++.(Horton)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470500883)

Once you get past the basics then look at the Meyers books, as stated in other answers.
[Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)

There are a couple of others from this author, they are real good but have not been updated in a long time.

A real good online [C++ FAQ is here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/).

If you put a comment stating what you plan to do with C++, we could give you narrower guidance to point you in the direction you want to go in

Answer (score 0):

If to choose only one book for high-quality development - Scott Meyers "Effective C++". Because there are *some* quirks in C++, and you will **definitely** hit them without this (or few similar) book. Also reading it is a pleasure (hence you can read it fast), because of a mix of humor and easy to understand insightful points.
But it's not a tutorial though.

I haven't ever tried "fast" tutorial, but here is pretty [good looking tutorial](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/). I think it's perfect for experienced programmer - short articles explaining distinct language features with some examples and comments